# ¿Cómo establezco el jdk que usa eclipse STS?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows10, spring-tool-suite

Cuando abro mi STS me sale este error:

[image: Spring Boot Live Hovers will not work without it]

Ya intenté ir a `Window > Preferences` y de allí en el dialogo a `Java > Installed JREs` y remplazar el JRE por un JDK allí.

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1

java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

where java
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Intentaste modificar las variables de sistema de windows?

Comment: @zerocool no porque ya están bien configuradas

Comment: Yo diría que no están bien configuradas. Concretamente, parece que el Path no es correcto. ¿Puedes hacer indicar su valor?

Comment: Por otro lado, revisa el fichero sts.ini y valida que tengas puesto -vm %ruta_a_tu_jdk/java.exe%

Comment: está bien configurado el Path y las variables de sistema, ya me acordé como se arreglaba y lo solucioné. gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Rusian: rechacé alguna sugerencia de modificación de extractos de etiquetas. Por favor lee [Escribamos extractos de etiquetas que expliquen cuándo usar la etiqueta, no qué es](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3935/83)